# BouncyCastle with JBoss in OpenShift

Tags: java, jboss, openshift, bouncycastle

Is is possible to use BouncyCastle with JBoss running in OpenShift?  I have unsuccessfully tried a couple of things.

The error that I am receiving is "java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC".

If BouncyCastle isn't able to be used is there another encryption provider available?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`

Comment: same error.  I previously had Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());